# how to create .dylib on xcode 4

Tags: xcode4, dylib

Apple dont seem to give instructions on how to set up a project

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/DynamicLibraries/100-Articles/CreatingDynamicLibraries.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002073-SW19

it seems easy to do on xcode 3, just select "BSD C Library" from Framework and Library, but in Xcode 4 there is no option to do that.

Comment: why has this been tagged with cocoa? i'm not linking with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose the C/C++ Library project template, which is under Framework and Library in Xcode 4. Click the Next button. Choose Dynamic from the Type menu to create a dynamic library.

Comment: How to export function from .dylib? In windows i use .def file what is similar in mac osx X-Code?

Comment: I don't know. I've never had the need to create a .dylib in Xcode.